# Not able to convert fla in Flash cs6 to avi successfully anymore

Tags: flash, flash-cs6, avi, fla

I successfully created an avi file through flash cs6. One day after I realized that I wanted just to alter some frames, I didn't do anything in the preferences... But now it creates unsupported files. They don't play anymore.

Comment: What are your current AVI export settings?  You'd probably have better luck exporting to QuickTime.  Changing the content of your timeline should not affect the output video's playability

Comment: Thank you @LDMS, I did did it with quicktime now and it worked :). I didn't change anything with my export settings, that is why I think it is so strange. Thanks again

Comment: Could be a codec change or other system variable outside of flash. What were trying to play it back with? Windows media player? VLC?

Comment: Both, in Windows media player it did not work at all, in VLC firstly comes up with an error message but then it played.